# What is the purpose of a parameter, with an underscore before it, that is not used inside the function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reading an article about how somebody went about building a data table with React - https://engineering.shopify.com/blogs/engineering/building-data-table-component-react. The following method is on the DataTable component. What is the purpose of the `_cell` parameter? It is not used inside the method!

```js
renderHeadingRow = (_cell, cellIndex) => {
    const { headings } = this.props;

    return (
        <Cell
            key={`heading-${cellIndex}`}
            content={headings[cellIndex]}
            header={true}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: try to put console.log(_cell) before return then you may get the idea of its purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscore is used in order the IDEs don't warn you about an unused parameter.
So, if you need to access the second parameter of the function but you won't use the first one, you can add an underscore to prevent the warning of unused parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a standard to show that the argument is never used inside the function scope but you would need to have it to access the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

_ Naming conventions are rarely used, and when used it is used to denote PRIVATE . Even though it cannot be really enforced by JavaScript, declaring something as private tells us about how it should be used or how it should not be used.

For instance, a private method in a class should only be used internally by the class, but should be avoided to be used on the instance of the class.

Read More Here : https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-naming-conventions